# how to install java when docker down

Tags: java, docker, installation

I am using docker(Docker version 1.13.1, build 07f3374/1.13.1) to run jenkins(jenkins/jenkins:2.164.1),the jenkins using openjdk.I removed container's openjdk and installed oracle jdk in container.But I restarted the container failed,`docker logs --tail="100" 4ed55631985b` show this error:

```
INFO: I/O exception (javax.net.ssl.SSLException) caught when processing request: java.lang.RuntimeEx                                         ception: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parame                                         ter must be non-empty
Mar 18, 2019 9:08:01 AM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry
INFO: Retrying request
Mar 18, 2019 9:08:01 AM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry
INFO: I/O exception (javax.net.ssl.SSLException) caught when processing request: java.lang.RuntimeEx                                         ception: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parame                                         ter must be non-empty
Mar 18, 2019 9:08:01 AM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry
INFO: Retrying request
Mar 18, 2019 9:09:24 AM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: JVM is terminating. Shutting down Jetty
/usr/local/bin/jenkins.sh: line 30: exec: java: not found
/usr/local/bin/jenkins.sh: line 30: exec: java: not found
```

How to fixed it when container is down? Should i reinstall the whole docker app?

Comment: Because I using the same gradlew command to build project,the local wrapped the dependency project jar to distination  jar file,and docker ci not wrapped the jar.the only difference is local machine using oracle jdk and the docker only have openjdk.so i do this@GhostCat

Comment: I just want to fix this problem.Is it possible?@GhostCat

Comment: When you removed open-jdk, are you sure you set all environment variable refer by jenkins during oracle jdk installation? Any particular reason to switch to oracle jdk from open jdk?

Comment: I just set JAVA_HOME and PATH variable in /etc/profile.I just want to keep the enviroment as same as possible with my develop machine@dkb

Comment: I changed the docker's java package.The docker's could not work,that is the problem.@GhostCat